# Unable to open .docx files in Windows 10 that have been created in Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, libreoffice, windows-10, doc

This issue occurs when I save a .docx file in an internal NTFS storage drive with Libreoffice 5.1.4 or AbiWord, then boot to Windows 10 on the same computer and attempt to open it in LibreOffice 5.1. The LibreOffice logo appears briefly, but nothing else seems to happen. It may be worth noting that this problem first occured when I attempted to open a .docx file created in Abiword, and then converted it to an .odt with Libreoffice on Ubuntu and tried to open it in Windows again, then saved as a .docx again, also with Libreoffice on Ubuntu, and failed to open it in Windows 10 again.

Comment: ".....tried to open it in Windows again," did it open successfully?

Comment: [https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/)

Comment: So, is it Window LO 5.1 vs Ubuntu LO 5.1.<b>4</b>? Perhaps behind that minor number hidden a fix? Also, as a user of office apps, you might be interested [in this research](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/community/osor/case/complex-singularity-versus-openness). **TL;DR**: *docx* is one of worst office formats, hard to implement compatibly, and not being consistently decoded/encoded even in MS Office. I.e. where Office 2010 shows a green triangle, Office 2007 has a red one. So it'd be much better both for you and the end users, if you'd use *odt* instead.

Comment: It appears that Abiword was somehow causing the problem, because a document created in Libreoffice on Ubuntu (instead of creating one in Abiword and then saving it as a different format with Libreoffice) seems to have no issues upon opening that file with Windows 10. I'm a noob here and am not sure whether to post this as an answer, or just leave this as a comment and continue to try to determine what is going on with documents created with Abiword here on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try saving as .odt in Ubuntu and opening that .odt in Windows?
The docx format seems to mess up pretty bad when edited on different platforms (well, even on the same platform, in fact), and even MS Office sometimes struggles with it's own documents format!
Unless the docx is mandatory, try to stick to open document formats.
Edit: if you **need** a MS-recognized format, try saving as the older .doc format, it should do the trick, as long you do not use fancy features...

Comment: Yes, I did try using a .odt, I believe, but I will try again. I will also try a .doc to see if that works. Thanks for the suggestions.